# How to get lowest and highest date from a table column?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, aggregate-functions, oracle19c

Am trying to get the lowest date and highest date from a table column. Am using below SQL query for that.

```
select MIN(trunc(TO_DATE(MOD_BEGIN, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))) AS MIN_DATUM
     , MAX(trunc(TO_DATE(MOD_END, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))) AS MAX_DATUM
from   V_IPSL_PPE_MUC_AZEIT;
```

FYI - Am using this query in PL/SQL. From the above query's output I will be generating date range. We are using oracle 19c.

But problem is these columns `MOD_BEGIN`, `MOD_END` have very few invalid values (e.g: 00000001000000) due to this when I execute the above query I get error message saying:

> ORA-01843: not a valid month
> ORA-02063: preceding line from L_IPSL_PPE_MUC

We are not allowed to cleanup this invalid data.

How to handle this scenario?

Comment: So it appears that MOD_BEGIN and MOD_END are not DATE but VARCHAR2?  If so that is a very serious design flaw.  And why are you not allowed to clean up data that is clearly incorrect?  That sounds like a serious management flaw.  On the other hand, if those columns ARE defined as DATE, then you should not be using TO_DATE, which uses a character string as input.  Using it on a DATE column forces an implied TO_CHAR before calling TO_DATE.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: As the strings are formatted 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS', you can just apply `MIN(mod_begin)` and `MAX(mod_end)`. If a result looks like `00000001000000`, tell them your query is correct and they shall fix the data. And EdStevens is correct of course; if someone designs a database with strings for dates, they must be ready to live with the consequences. The real solution is to fix the inappropriate table design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are running Oracle 12.2 or higher, this might be an handy place to use `ON CONVERSION ERROR`:

```
select 
    trunc(min(to_date(mod_begin default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) as min_datum,
    trunc(max(to_date(mod_end   default null on conversion error, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) as max_datum 
from v_ipsl_ppe_muc_azeit;
```

When an invalid date is met, `to_date()` returns `null` instead of erroring; then the surrounding aggregate function ignore `null` values.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. We are on 19c, it worked.

Comment: Now for one of the table am getting : ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-02063: preceding line from L_IPSL_PPE_OXF
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis". When I change the table to the above one, it just works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution can be using custom conversion function which will return NULL in case of conversion error:

```
FUNCTION convert_date (p_str IN varchar2, p_format varchar2)

RETURN DATE IS

BEGIN

    RETURN  TO_DATE(p_str , p_format);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN NULL;

END convert_date ;
```

And use this function in your code:

```
select 
    trunc(min(convert_date (mod_begin, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) as min_datum,
    trunc(max(convert_date (mod_end, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))) as max_datum 
from v_ipsl_ppe_muc_azeit;
```

Comment: This actually works well especially with the dblinks. Using `default null on conversion error` with database links (View) in sql query has lead me to error ORA-02063: preceding line from string.